# Aspherical spaces: does it mean that spheres do not present?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

In almost all the introductions by various authors on cohomology of groups, a reference work of  Hurewicz is given, mentioning that

> He defined aspherical spaces. These are spaces $X$ such that $\pi_n(X)=0$ for $n>1$. Then $X$ is determined up to homotopy by fundamental group $\pi_1(X)$.

I am curious about the terminology ''aspherical''.

In $\pi_1(X)$, roughly, we are looking circles or circular curves in space $X$.

So when we think about a space $Y$ such that $\pi_n(Y)=0$, for $n>1$, should we consider it as non-presence of Euclidean spheres of dimension $2$ or higher?

(My question is philosophical; I want to know that when, in a lecture/discussion, if speaker says the statement "...let $X$ be an aspherical space " in above sence of Hurewicz, it is appropriate to think as non-existence of sphres of dimensions
$>1$?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that for any $n>1$, any map $f\colon S^n\to X$ is nullhomotopic, i.e., extends over the disk $D^{n+1}$. So there are "no spheres" up to homotopy (for dimensions $>1$).

One interesting question to consider is how an aspherical space can have nontrivial homology groups in higher dimensions. For example, $\Bbb R P^\infty$ is aspherical, but it has infinitely many nonzero homology groups.